# Configuring postfix on an Ubuntu (natty narwhal) Amazon Ec2 instance for php mail()

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

I'm setting up sendmail and postfix for the first time.  I believe it's installed correctly, but I need assistance with the configuration.
When I call mail(), I get the following in /var/log/mail.log

```
Aug 30 06:13:52 ip-10-202-193-59 postfix/pickup[28117]: 866186010F: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Aug 30 06:13:52 ip-10-202-193-59 postfix/cleanup[28125]: 866186010F: message-id=<20110830061352.866186010F@ip-10-202-193-59.ec2.internal> 
Aug 30 06:13:52 ip-10-202-193-59 postfix/qmgr[28118]: 866186010F: from=<www-data@bellcreativestudio.com>, size=392, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 30 06:13:52 ip-10-202-193-59 postfix/smtp[28127]: 866186010F: to=<ryanbell@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.113.27]:25, delay=0.$
Aug 30 06:13:52 ip-10-202-193-59 postfix/qmgr[28118]: 866186010F: removed
```

The message is never delivered.

My postfix configuration is as follows:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = bellcreativestudio.com, ip-10-202-193-59.ec2.internal, localhost.ec2.internal, localhost
myhostname = bellcreativestudio.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postfix transaction log looks fine. You might check the "spam" folder on gmail just in case it is misclassified as such (possibly due to your configuration) and wound up there.

Comment: Wow.  Problem solved!  Good call.

Comment: Happens too often... Glad it worked out!